# What is the AWS Service Principal value for stepfunction?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-step-functions

I'm writing the terraform for creating  an IAM role for AWS StepFunctions. 
What should be the value for **Principal**  in **assume_role_policy**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "stepfunctions.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm getting the error

> Error: Error creating IAM Role my_utility_sfn: MalformedPolicyDocument: Invalid principal in policy: "SERVICE":"stepfunctions.amazonaws.com"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The AWS documentation for [service endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/step-functions.html) should hold the answer.

Looks like it is `states.<region>.amazonaws.com`

Answer (score 1):

The principal is `states.<region>.amazonaws.com` :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-lambda-state-machine-cloudformation.html#lambda-state-machine-cfn-create-role

Answer (score 0):

In short, the correct Service Principal for AWS Step Functions is:

```
states.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).